# Binomial distribution and approximation with stirling

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, approximation, binomial-distribution

X ${\sim}$ Bin(n,p) random variable, and $ε > 0, p ≤ 1/2$ satisfy $ε²pn ≥ 3.$

I need to Prove that $$P(X ≤ (1 − ε)pn) ≥ e^{\large{−9ε²pn}}$$

Pretty sure I should use the stirling approximation but I don't know how.

some help please?

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html (26)

p.s.

at the same question you need to prove that $P(X \ge (1 + ε)pn)≥ e^{−9ε²pn}$

but I guess it's similar...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stirling's approximation for binomial dist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3874813/stirlings-approximation-for-binomial-dist)

Comment: there is no answer there... so unfortunately no. do you have any clue?

Comment: I have no clue at the moment. The main reason that I don´t no what  means. Use $\LaTeX$ to make it  clearly legible. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a basic tutorial.

Comment: is it better now? do you have any clue maybe?

Comment: Is it $$P(X ≤ (1 − ε)pn) ≥ e^{\large{−9ε²pn}}?$$ Btw, you need only two $-signs for one line.

Comment: yes exactly! thank you, I'll notice that next time.

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Not really, sorry